# How to consistently idenfity USB devices with udev

Tags: usb, udev, devices

I have a udev rule for a USB cable with 2 serial ports
that successfully matches ttyUSB*x* to /dev/ttyUC*x*

`KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="ttyUC%n"`

My problem is as follows:
If I have no other USB devices, then I end up with /dev/ttyUC0 and /dev/ttyUC1

But, when there is another USB device I could end up with

/dev/ttyUC0 and /dev/ttyUC1
**OR**
/dev/ttyUC1 and /dev/ttyUC2

Is there any way to ensure that I always get the **same** symlink names (no matter what other USB devices are present)?